# Magento: how to use removeItem for js files added by extension programatically

Tags: php, xml, magento, layout, themes

I have a 3rd party extension adding JS in via an observer:

```
<?php
class Anowave_Owl_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function dispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('owl') && Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('owl')->getSlider())
        {
            $format = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('owl')->getFormat();

            if ($format instanceof Anowave_Owl_Block_Format)
            {
                $format->addCss()->addJs();
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Where addJs is defined in a block class as:

```
public function addJs()
{
    $script = 'js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
    Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addItem('skin_js', $script);
 }
```

Rather than hack the module, I'm trying to remove the loaded jquery via removeItem i.e.

```
   <default>
     <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
   </default>
```

In local.xml. But it does not work. (That JS file is still printed into a script tag in the head). 
i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.local/skin/frontend/base/default/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

I know that my syntax and pathing are correct because I can unload/remove other JS files this way in the same folder (ones which are specified by their extension's layout XML instead). 
I thought local.xml was processed after all other layout registration steps, but I guess not (?) 
So I don't think removeItem in layout is an option. 
I'd be willing to use

```
        Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->removeItem('skin_js', $script);
```

In a custom module, but how would i know that all the previous addJS() processing has finished executing?

Any ideas or solutions appreciated!

Comment: Doe you get any errors or what does "but it does not work" means in detail?

Comment: There are no errors in the php log or the magento logs. 
My goal is to stop magento from outputting that jQuery script tag in the head which is what it's doing now.

 `code  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.local/skin/frontend/base/default/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

but after I add my removeItem action in layout.xml it does not prevent that script tag from being rendered, presumably because layout.xml is being processed before addItem (a guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered in detail in a crosspost to magento.stackexchange:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74778/magento-how-to-use-removeitem-for-js-files-added-by-extension-programatically/74781#74781

Answer (score 2):

If this 3rd party extension is in the `community` code pool you can recreate the same path of this observer in the `local` code pool, Magento will check the presence of the class in the local code pool first before any other.

You have to create the path `app/code/local/Anowave/Owl/Model/` and place the `Observer.php` file inside it so you can safely modify this class for your business logic without hacking the original extension.

Comment: The extension is in the local pool in this particular case.